# microsoft knowledge base article 810886 + Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, debugging

When i run my asp.net web application i got this error,

```
An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring 
changes to 'Z:\CR-FIRST\app_code\model' because the network BIOS command limit 
has been reached. For more information on this error, please refer to Microsoft 
knowledge base article 810886. Hosting on a UNC share is not supported for the 
Windows XP Platform.
```

Why i get this error ... Any suggestion....

Comment: Have you referred to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810886 like the error message suggests?

Comment: @Anon My application folder is in a network drive...

Comment: that's what the KB article is talking about. I suggest you read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand your network drive maps to a UNC path like \\computer\something. So Microsoft is describing your situation - the two concepts are one in the same. You'll have to move your website off the network drive, or put a web server on that computer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to host a on a network drive or UNC and your OS is XP?

That is not supported.

Comment: is is too early to put a schmaltzy 'wink' in the answer? lol.

Comment: i guess my humor was not understood or appreciated. It would have been hard to answer this one with a straight face.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://www.garrypassarella.co.uk/2012/03/21/network-bios-command-limit-has-been-reached-hosting-on-a-unc-share-is-not-supported-for-the-windows-xp-platform/) helped me. It walks you through a few different things to try...

> #### 1. Add Registry value
>
> Locate the following key in the syustem registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET Add a
> DWORD FCNMode and set the value to a decimal with the value 1. Restart
> Visual Studio to ensure the new setting is found.
>
> #### 2. Add Registry value
>
> Another registry edit here. Locate the following key in the system registry
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ASP.NET Add a
> DWORD FCNMode and set the value to a decimal with the value 2. Restart
> Visual Studio to ensure the new setting is found.
>
> #### 3. The project is stored on an internal netword
>
> Depending on how your company’s network is configured Visual Studio may store the
> project on a network drive. Moving the project to a local drive on
> your machine and trying to run it again has been known to resolve this
> issue.
>
> #### 4. MSDN Fix
>
> This comes directly from this article on MSDN; http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810886/en-us – I’ve trimmed it down a
> little. Verify that the MaxCmds and MaxMpxCt registry values are set
> to 50 or more. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
> 2. Locate and then click the following key in the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanworkstation\parameters
> 3. In the right pane, double-click the MaxCmds value.
> 4. In the Value data box, verify that the value is 50 or more.
> 5. Locate and then click the following key in the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters Note
>    Make sure that you make this change to
>    the lanmanserver\parameters registry key and not to
>    the lanmanworkstation\parameters registry key mentioned in step 2.
> 6. In the right-pane, double-click the MaxMpxCt value. Note On SMB servers that are running a version of Windows earlier than Windows
>    2000, the MaxMpxCt registry entry is named MaxMpxCount, but has the
>    same function.
> 7. In the Value data box, verify that the value is 50 or more. Note The MaxMpxCt value determines the maximum number of simultaneous,
>    active requests that the server permits from an individual client.
> 8. Quit Registry Editor.
> 9. Restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Another specific case that triggers the same message is if the project is on a mapped drive that points back to the same PC.

For historic reasons, I have `D:` on my PC mapped to `C:\D_Drive` through a share on the same PC.  Loading the solution from `D:\Source\MyMVC\MyMVC.sln` gives this error, but loading it from `C:\D_Drive\Source\MyMVC\MyMVC.sln` (where it "really" lives) worked fine.